# Average formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a spreadsheet and I need to have a set of cells ignored if they are blank.  I tried a regular average formula as well as if statements and nothing seems to be working.  The values need to be adjusted so they come to a common value.  Here is the formula I am trying to use to calculate the average.

```
=(AVERAGE(D4,(F4*0.6),(H4*(6/7))))
```

This formula will calculate the average but is not ignoring cells that do not have a value.

Comment: What about `=AverageIf([average range],"<>""")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel should automatically ignore truly blank cells when using the `=Average()` formula.  However, if you do have some `"0"` data or space characters, you could use the following to find the average of anything that is numeric:

```
=SUM(A:A)/COUNT(A:A)
```

Where `A:A` is your range.

---

EDIT: Simplified to use `Count` [which only finds numeric cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNT-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c).

---

EDIT 2: Given your specific example, the average function could look as follows:

```
=IFERROR((D4 + (F4*0.6) + (H4*(6/7)))/COUNTA(D4,F4,H4), 0)
```